# sql query "WHERE IN"

Tags: sql, where-clause

I have this query :

```
SELECT Company_Name FROM tblBeneficaries WHERE BeneficaryID IN ()
```

When I execute it it returns the message:

> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because, your `IN` clause has no parameter/argument `WHERE BeneficaryID IN ()`. It should be `WHERE BeneficaryID IN (id1,id2,id3, ...,idn)`

Your current query is same as saying below, no need of the `WHERE` condition

```
SELECT Company_Name FROM tblBeneficaries
```

Answer (score 6):

Your query as it reads should return no rows, because the set of desired BeneficaryIDs is empty. This syntax however is not valid, as the IN clause *must* contain at least one value, unfortunately. In order to represent an empty set, add NULL:

```
SELECT Company_Name FROM tblBeneficaries WHERE BeneficaryID IN (NULL);
```

This is useful when building the query dynamically, where you end up with zero or more elements in the set, i.e. `(NULL)` for an empty set or `(NULL, 4, 16)` for a set of numbers 4 and 16, for instance.

It is still an annoying limitation on the IN clause and the trick shown doesn't work with NOT IN! (Adding NULL would prevent you from fetching *any* record, so you would have to use a non-null value that's never used, such as `WHERE BeneficaryID NOT IN (-1)`).

Answer (score 2):

Syntax of [**IN**  SQL](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) :

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name IN (value1,value2,...);
```

Provide values between () in below query :

```
SELECT Company_Name FROM tblBeneficaries WHERE BeneficaryID IN ()
```

> Your **values are missing** that throws you error.

Check demo example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_in).

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the parameters in the in condition.

please find the below link for the correct way of using WHERE IN :

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

Answer (score 1):

You need to add values for the `IN` operator:
For instance:

```
SELECT Company_Name FROM tblBeneficaries WHERE BeneficaryID IN (1,2,3,4)
```

Read in [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) for the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Company_Name
FROM tblBeneficaries
WHERE BeneficaryID IN (1,2,3,4)
```

Execute like this by replacing the () by your `BeneficaryID`, if `BeneficaryID` is `INT`. 
 Add `''` for the values if `BeneficaryID` is `VARCHAR`, like `('1', '2')`