# How can I delete multiple images based on an ID of a record from a table?

Tags: php, php-8

I have a system to publish articles with images, but when deleting the article, it deletes only one image and not all the images that were uploaded from that article.

```
<?php

include('assets/system/core.php');

$id = $_GET['id'];

$consulta = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM images WHERE id2 = '$id' ");
$registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta);

$ruta = $registro['file_name'];

unlink("uploads/".$ruta);

$query = mysqli_query($db,"DELETE FROM amenidades WHERE id = '$id'");
$query2 = mysqli_query($db,"DELETE FROM images WHERE id2 = '$id'");
$query3 = mysqli_query($db,"DELETE FROM propiedades WHERE id = '$id'");
$query4 = mysqli_query($db,"DELETE FROM visit_days WHERE id = '$id'");
$query4 = mysqli_query($db,"DELETE FROM comments WHERE prpdad_id = '$id'");
header("LOCATION: ".$web_settings['weblink']."mispropiedades.php");
```

How could I delete all the images corresponding to a record from my database?

Comment: As per the documentation mysqli_fetch_assoc returns one row at a time. To get all rows use mysqli_fetch_all() and loop through the results

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391315)

Comment: You haven't shared any code that tries to delete multiple images after all. Shouldn't there be any loop?

Comment: Use [sql query "WHERE IN"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31912845/sql-query-where-in).  Deleting something should not be a simple GET request, in addition to the SQL injection problem mentioned already. Also `$query4` is assigned twice - just in case that causes confusion.